# Multiple post pagination on same page with Timber

Tags: wordpress, pagination, twig, custom-post-type, timber

I recently implemented a blog that takes content from two post types and displays them in a tabbed navigation. The problem I encounter is that I can't seem to be able to create pagination links for each post type without one overriding the other.

```
<div id="view1">
  {% block content %} {% for post in posts %} {% include ['tease-'~post.post_type~'.twig', 'tease.twig'] %} {% endfor %} {% endblock %}
  <div class="tool-pagination">
    <ul class="pages">
      <li>
        {% if pagination.prev %}
        <a href="{{pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% for page in pagination.pages %}
      <li>
        {% if page.link %}
        <a href="{{page.link}}" class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</a>
        {% else %}
        <span class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li><a href="{{pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {% if pagination.next %} {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Workbench  Tab -->
<div id="view2">
  {% block workbench %} {% for post in workbench %} {% include ['tease-'~post.post_type~'.twig', 'tease.twig'] %} {% endfor %} {% endblock %}
  <div class="tool-pagination">
    <ul class="pages">
      <li>
        {% if pagination.prev %}
        <a href="{{pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% for page in pagination.pages %}
      <li>
        {% if page.link %}
        <a href="{{page.link}}" class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</a>
        {% else %}
        <span class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li><a href="{{pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {% if pagination.next %} {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

My index.php file looks like this:

```
$context['pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();
```

I tried following the instructions on the timber site pagination but all I've managed to do is choose which category is paginated not both

Thanks in advance!!
Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple pagination wasn't something I really anticipated for. But here's how I *think* it could work:

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['posts_pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();

$query = array('post_type' => 'workbench');
$context['workbench'] = Timber::get_posts($query);
query_posts($query); //this forces WP to rerun query stuff
$context['workbench_pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();
```

This is not tested, but based on what you got, this is the closest stab I can take

Comment: Thanks Jared I'll give this a try!

Comment: Sweet! I've just got an issue where I'm getting empty data from Timber and this fixed it

Comment: oh @Jared I've got filters in my $query var (to use the context of this question), I want the pagination links to use those filters in the query, how do I do that? is there a way